# Hashicorp vault - issue with 'personal vault' policies

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to setup a kv2 mount called 'personal' where each user will have his own cubbyhole...that doesn't expire. Say the company has 100 employees - they have company-wide secrets in mounts such as secrets/ , secrets/general, secrets/general/dept and so on, however I'd like each of them to have read/write access to personal/user, without other users being able to read there. How can I obtain this? I figured a policy such as this would suffice:

```
path "personal/data/user/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "delete", "update", "list", "sudo"]
}
path "personal/user/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "delete", "update", "list", "sudo"]
}
path "personal/+" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}
```

This, however, doesn't work as i'd like. I mean, i can get the secret from cli:

```
    master* ± vault kv get personal/user/ipam |head 
    ====== Metadata ======
    Key              Value
    ---              -----
    created_time     2019-08-27T14:01:10.156868866Z
    deletion_time    n/a
    destroyed        false
    version          3

    ====== Data ======
    Key         Value
```

but vault-ui doesn't let me access the 'personal/' space:

```
master* 2 ± vault kv list personal/
Error listing personal/metadata: Error making API request.

URL: GET https://...:8200/v1/personal/metadata?list=true
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
```

If i update the last path to "personal/*", user can read everyone else's paths (not secrets, but paths), which is what i'd like to avoid.

Anybody has any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [ACL templating](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/policy-templating)

The policy would look something like this

```
path "personal/{{identity.entity.name}}/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```

Depending on your auth method (LDAP for example), you might need to change the templated path to something like `identity.entity.aliases.<<mount accessor>>.name`